# Pi Zero V1.3 miniuart not working

Tags: pi-zero, uart, bare-metal

Ive got a bare metal project that has been running on Pi 3 without problems, i want to start moving it over to the Pi Zero, i have a V1.3 Pi Zero (not W) here so started with that.  Ive stripped it all down to the basics but even the mini uart doesnt appear to be working.

Ive updated the base from 0x3F000000 to 0x20000000 and tried various options in the config.txt file.  Currently im using the following

```
arm_64bit=1
uart_2ndstage=1
core_freq=250

[pi0]
kernel=kernel-rpi0.img
enable_uart=1

[pi3]
kernel=kernel8-rpi3.img
dtoverlay=miniuart-bt

[pi4]
kernel=kernel8-rpi4.img
dtoverlay=miniuart-bt
```

but without success.  I get all the 2nd stage uart output fine, its loading the right kernel file

```
MESS:00:00:03.630791:0: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/kernel-rpi0.img
MESS:00:00:03.635105:0: Loading 'kernel-rpi0.img' to 0x80000 size 0x4cc
```

From reading other posts ive made sure the command line file has

console=serial0,115200

And tried various options with dtoverlay and enable_uart etc.  As it all worked on pi 3 and pi 4 i assumed it would be a simple switch but it doesnt appear to be :(

Ive even gone back to someone elses setup which again works on pi 3 and 4 but not zero

```
    REGS_AUX->enables = 1;
    REGS_AUX->mu_control = 0;
    REGS_AUX->mu_ier = 0;
    REGS_AUX->mu_lcr = 3;
    REGS_AUX->mu_iir = 0xc6;
    REGS_AUX->mu_mcr = 0;

#if RPI_VERSION == 3
    REGS_AUX->mu_baud_rate = 270;
#endif

#if RPI_VERSION == 4
    REGS_AUX->mu_baud_rate = 541;
#endif

#if RPI_VERSION == 0
    REGS_AUX->mu_baud_rate = 270;
#endif

    REGS_AUX->mu_control = 3;
```

Any ideas would be great.  Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking or what you have done BUT one thing is clear. The PiZero DOES NOT have a 64bit CPU.

Comment: Ahh you are right, that could very well be my issue :D ill give it a go

Comment: Thansk @Milliways, works a treat, something so obvious :D